# Tcl: Check for same content between two files

Tags: tcl, diff

I have a program which I made in vimscript which checks two files if they are the same. It makes a system call to `diff` to verify if they are differents or not.

I need something similar in Tcl but without resorting to external commands or system calls. I don't need to know the difference or have comparison between the files, just to return 1 if both files have the same content or 0 if the contents are different.

Comment: No code, attempt or whatsoever effort from your part?

Comment: @Jerry I read chapter 11: Accesing Files from J.K. Ousterhout book, but could not find a command for comparing files. Checked online, but I could only find file comparisons where the differences are given/shown and I just wanted something more simple as to whether files are the same or not.

Comment: Ok, the first thing is, your question really looks like you are asking for code writing service. Maybe you should read the [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page (or go through it once more if you did at least once before). Second, I would have expected it to be easier to try understanding the code you found and remove the unnecessary parts to get what you're looking for, and if there are any issues, then you could put the problematic part in your question to show you also put effort in it.

Comment: @Jerry What is wrong with code writing service? Some people are generous, kind and more knowledgeable than I am. Why shouldn't I get benefits from them? They are great people and they always helping me. In contrast I found a lot of programmers in "Stack Overflow" think they are better than everybody else when beginners ask "stupid" or "silly" questions, and unfortunately I found a lot of this here. Instead of directing them to the right problem they start belittle them and being patronising, and that is very sad. IMHO

Comment: @milapera I think you are getting the wrong idea here. Maybe you should read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260828/do-we-need-a-close-reason-for-zero-effort-questions) then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
proc comp_file {file1 file2} {
    # optimization: check file size first
    set equal 0
    if {[file size $file1] == [file size $file2]} {
        set fh1 [open $file1 r]
        set fh2 [open $file2 r]
        set equal [string equal [read $fh1] [read $fh2]]
        close $fh1
        close $fh2
    }
    return $equal
}

if {[comp_file /tmp/foo /tmp/bar]} {
    puts "files are equal"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For a straight binary comparison, you can just work a chunk at a time. (4kB is probably quite enough per chunk though you can pick larger values; I/O overhead will dominate in any case.) The simplest way to express this is with a loop inside a `try`…`finally` (requires Tcl 8.6):

```
proc sameContent {file1 file2} {
    set f1 [open $file1 "rb"]
    set f2 [open $file2 "rb"]
    try {
        while 1 {
            if {[read $f1 4096] ne [read $f2 4096]} {
                return 0
            } elseif {[eof $f1]} {
                # The same if we got to EOF at the same time
                return [eof $f2]
            } elseif {[eof $f2]} {
                return 0
            }
        }
    } finally {
        close $f1
        close $f2
    }
}
```

Otherwise, we can take advantage of the fact that we can see if a variable has been set to keep the logic fairly simple (which is quite a lot less clear) to make code that works in older versions of Tcl:

```
proc sameContent {file1 file2} {
    set f1 [open $file1]
    fconfigure $f1 -translation binary
    set f2 [open $file2]
    fconfigure $f2 -translation binary
    while {![info exist same]} {
        if {[read $f1 4096] ne [read $f2 4096]} {
            set same 0
        } elseif {[eof $f1]} {
            # The same if we got to EOF at the same time
            set same [eof $f2]
        } elseif {[eof $f2]} {
            set same 0
        }
    }
    close $f1
    close $f2
    return $same
}
```

Both are invoked in the same way:

```
if {[sameContent "./foo.txt" "some/dir/bar.txt"]} {
    puts "They're the same contents, byte-for-byte"
} else {
    puts "A difference was found"
}
```

Comment: I performed a test for speed. I tried to compare different files, text and binaries, and different sizes, from 1KB to 70MB. Glenn's procedure seems a lot faster. On average the Tcl 8.6 version comes last with 21 microseconds, then the one for older versions with 19 microseconds, but Glenn's code manages to achieve 2 microseconds. I think the difference is that your code is optimize to deal with binary and Glenn's with text files?

Comment: probably because I do the file size check. that will avoid file io if the files are obviously different. Seeing Donal's approach, I would add the file size check to his chunk-by-chunk reading.